# Not able to publish Avro messages to Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I started Kafka by using the following command

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 -p 8081:8081 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine active\`` --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
```

Now, I wrote a simple program which posts a string into a kafka topic. it works without any problems.

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.99.100:9092")
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
val inputRecord = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("test", "key2", "Hello World")
producer.send(inputRecord)
producer.close()
```

So now I modified this program and try to send an avro message into the kafka topic

```
val props = new Properties()
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.99.100:9092")
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://192.168.99.100:8081")
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer")
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, Object](props)
val inputRecord = createAvroRecord(schemaStr, "test1", "test1")
val producer: KafkaProducer[String, Object] = CreateProducerAvro
val producerAvroRecord = new ProducerRecord[String, Object]("test", "key1", inputRecord)
producer.send(producerAvroRecord)
producer.close()
```

But I get error

```
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.utils.RestUtils.httpRequest(RestUtils.java:128)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.utils.RestUtils.registerSchema(RestUtils.java:174)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:51)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:89)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:49)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:424)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:339)
    at KafkaPublisher$.SendAvroMessage(KafkaPublisher.scala:35)
    at KafkaPublisher$.main(KafkaPublisher.scala:20)
    at KafkaPublisher.main(KafkaPublisher.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your key.serializer and value.serializer to avro as below.

```
props.put("key.serializer", io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put("value.serializer", io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
```

If you are using schema registry, set the schema registry url

```
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
```

Note:
Set your schema registry url to the server where you are running schema registry with the subject name "Kafka-value"
If you are not using the above, you can discard this.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that you are working on windows or at least with the docker machine and the ip adress that you're setting on `bootstrap_servers` and `schema.registry.url` is docker machine ip adress.

Try to remove the two options :`ADVERTISED_HOST` and `ADVERTISED_PORT`, normally your ports bindings are enough in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates a connection error, very likely because no schema registry was found. I couldn't find any information that `spotify/kafka` includes a schema registry in the docker image.

If you are not running a schema registry at `8081` check out the [Confluent page about schema registry](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html).

A quick fix would be to run a docker container with the following configuration:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest
    container_name: schema-registry
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: localhost # the host name of the schema registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: host.docker.internal:9092 # the kafka broker, in this case docker host machine
```

The above configuration would return `{}` if you access `http://localhost:8081` (an empty schema with no auth).

And don't forget to remove the port binding `8081` from the `spotify/kafka` container.